# Communicating across modules with Prism?

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

From following the Prism documentation it says there are four ways to communicate across modules -

- Solution commanding
- Region context
- Shared services
- Event aggregation

  1. Can I just chose one of these methods and apply it for all cross-module communcation? Or should I use different methods depending on the situation?
  2. In particular, in an application Im writing at the moment I have button in one module and when the user clicks it I want to start a thread in another module. Which method of communication would I use for this situation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Ans 1**: Yes, you can use a single approach all-over. Most of the times it will be easier to do it that way.

**Ans 2**: I recommend you use *Event Aggregation* to do that. That way, you have a very loose coupling between the button click and the thread execution. That way, the *listening module* just has to be aware of a single *event* no matter where it was raised from.

Since, it is a single *notification* and not a bunch of inter-related *notifications/communications*, it is better to *Aggregate* an event rather than creating a *Shared Service*.

Comment: Lets assume I have two modules namely Purchase and Stock. So how can I handle transaction across two modules? If there is any error in Purchase or in stock then transaction should rollback.