# Communication between loosely coupled Components using Prism for UWP App

Tags: c#, uwp, prism

I am new to Prism and have been looking into designing a UWP App which would have 2 XAML views. These 2 views would be loosely coupled and i want to pass messages between the 2 views. One view would have a button and on clicking on this button, a message would be sent to the other view which would highlight and item in the list in that view. I am reading up on the Prism documentation and have some confusion about what would be the best form of communication? In particular would my case benefit from Solution Commanding or using the IEvent Aggregator. Referencing this post [Communicating across modules with Prism?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8625290/communicating-across-modules-with-prism) i would love to understand why IEeventAggregator is a good solution

Comment: Does the below answer your question? Or what is your actual question?

Comment: I think my confusion is in specific between Event Aggregator and Solution Commanding. From the description it seems like both seem to be doing the same thing so why is one better than the other?

Comment: Which one to use depends on whether you expect an immediate action from the user. Please see my edited answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of using an event aggregator is to remove the tight copuling between the producer and consumer of an event or a message.

If you want to send a message from one component to another in your application, you *can* do this by raising an event or calling a method of a strong reference to the consumer. The downside of doing this is that you create a strong dependency between the subscriber and publisher classes and this makes the application harder and more expensive to maintain.

The solution is to introduce an event aggregator in between the publisher and subscriber. Then the subscriber and the publisher only know about the event aggregator. They don't know anything about each other which means that they can evolve independently from one another.

Please refer to [this blog post](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2014/02/28/using-the-event-aggregator-pattern-to-communicate-between-view-models/) for more information about the concept.

Edit: To answer your actual question, **solution commanding** is generally used when there is an expectation of *immediate action* from the user interaction whereas **event aggregation** is used when there is not a direct action-reaction expectation.

Please refer to the [docs](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/wpf/legacy/Communication.html) for more information.

Comment: The question seems to about _why use the event aggregator_ (as opposed to a specialized service for example), not really about the benefits over regular events.